# Align horizontalcenter in Column

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

`Column` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) explains how to achieve this:

[image]

However, I would like to achieve this:

[image]

That is, all items inside the `Column` should be horizontally aligned to the center. `anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.Center` does not work. How can I obtain the desired result?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the answer was accepted and now the post is edited that it does not work. So does it or does it not?

Comment: I've had already tried `anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.Center` even before I posted. But that was wrong. What you wrote was right: `anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter`. The difference is to use `parent.horizontalCenter` and not `parent.Center`.

Comment: yeah, after posting the comment I read it the second time and understood the difference, damn I must pay more attention to reading:D Sorry for the pointless comment:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you can use `anchors.horizontalCenter` for all the child items to align them with the `horizontalCenter` of the column given that the column has an id you can refer to.

Comment: You should not used anchors inside layouts: "Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout."

Comment: `Column` is not a layout.

Comment: The [Detailed Description of Column](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html#details) is quite specific about what properties of `anchors` shall not be used. `horizontalCenter` is not mentioned. So I think the comments by @patrick-josé-pereira @marpan are obsolete.

Answer (score 21):

Try to put this line to every child:

```
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a matter of laying out your items, also take a look at the `ColumnLayout` component and the attached property `Layout.alignment` (you can set it as `Qt.AlignHCenter`).

I find layouts far easier to use.

Comment: The downside of layouts is that they don't have transitions eg for move. Or at least I don't know how to apply them.

Comment: If you want to move items around, it's not only a matter of laying out them. :-)

Comment: I did it this way as the doc said, but Qt sets the left side of the items in the center position, instead of centering the whole item with equal margins left and right. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Savvas, the `Layout` is an [attached object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) that can be used in children of the `ColumnLayout`. You can set the attached property `Layout.alignment` in each child that you want to center, as you would have set `anchors.horizontalCenter` in each child of a `Column`.